# Django - Move password_reset templates

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-registration

I have the following architecture:

```
Project/
    templates/
        aaa/              #This is my application main templates folder
        registration/
            password_reset_complete.html
            password_reset_form.html
            password_reset_email.html
            password_reset_confirm.html
    aaa/
```

I would like to move `password_reset` templates files and destroy the `registration` folder to get the following architecture:

```
Project/
    templates/
        aaa/                          #This is my application main templates folder
            password_reset_complete.html
            password_reset_form.html
            password_reset_confirm.html
        mails/
            password_reset_email.html
    aaa/
```

I guess I can override `password_reset_complete`, `password_reset_form`, `password_reset_confirm` url patterns, but how to do for the `password_reset_email` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can change the `template_name` argument passed to each `django.contrib.auth` views. The `password_reset` view has several templates filename passed in parameter that you can customize.
According to [the Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py), it should be something like this, in your URL patterns:

```
 (r'^accounts/reset_password/$', 
      'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',  
      {'template_name': 'aaa/password_reset_form.html',
       'email_template_name': 'mails/password_reset_email.html'}),

 (r'^accounts/reset_confirm/$', 
      'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',  
      {'template_name': 'aaa/password_reset_confirm.html'}),

 (r'^accounts/reset_complete/$', 
      'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',  
      {'template_name': 'aaa/password_reset_complete.html'}),
```